# Building spring integration route on the fly

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I need to build a small reporting application that is producing a report from a database. For now there are just 2 reports that are cronned daily and weekly. OK folks this is what I'm trying to do to make it easily extendable in the future.

1) Scan reports directory for *.properties files whose content is like this:
    report.name=Weekly Management report
    report.datasource=myDataSource
    report.bootstrap.sql=SELECT getdate()
    report.cron.expression=* 0/2 * * * MON-FRI
    report.service.activator.class=reporting.qvalent.JDBCReportExtractor
    report.recipient.email=konstantin@localhost

2) For each file, create a spring integration route that will do the following:
 a) poll database with a bootstrap query according to cron expression
 b) invoke activator class that will actually gather all required data from the datasource and maybe enrich Thymeleaf context
 c) merge thymeleaf context with the template and email it

What I do now is this:

```
public class ReportDefinitionLoader implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {
       private ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory;

private void prepareBeansForReport(Resource resource) throws IOException {
    try {
        Properties props = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
        String reportName = props.getProperty(REPORT_NAME_PROPERTY);
        String reportDatasource = props.getProperty(REPORT_DATASOURCE_PROPERTY);
        String reportCronExpression = props.getProperty(REPORT_CRON_EXPRESSION_PROPERTY);
        String reportBootstrapQuery = props.getProperty(REPORT_BOOTSTRAP_QUERY_PROPERTY);
        CronTrigger cronTrigger = new CronTrigger(reportCronExpression);
        beanFactory.registerSingleton(reportName + CRON_TRIGGER_BEAN_NAME, cronTrigger);
        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) beanFactory.getBean(reportDatasource);
        beanFactory.getBean()
        beanFactory.autowireBean(dataSource);
        QueueChannel channel1 = new QueueChannel();
        JdbcPollingChannelAdapter jdbcPollingChannelAdapter = new JdbcPollingChannelAdapter(dataSource, reportBootstrapQuery);
        SourcePollingChannelAdapter adapter = new SourcePollingChannelAdapter();
        TimerManagerTaskScheduler taskScheduler = new TimerManagerTaskScheduler();
        taskScheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

            }
        }, cronTrigger);
        adapter.setOutputChannel(channel1);
        adapter.setSource(jdbcPollingChannelAdapter);
        adapter.setBeanFactory(beanFactory);
        adapter.setTaskScheduler(taskScheduler);
        adapter.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.error("Could not load properties from resource: " + resource.getFile().getName(), e);
    }
}
}
```

But the dataSource bean is having unresolved properties as defined in the XML

```
  <bean id="myDataSource" class = "com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
  <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}" />
  <property name="user" value="${jdbc.user}" />
  <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
```

Can you please advise how do I get the bean from Spring context for further using it in another class that would also be placed under spring context? At the moment, I'm getting these when it starts up:

```
2014-09-04 11:15:12,545 [WARN] - Could not load driverClass ${jdbc.driver}
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ${jdbc.driver}
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.ensureDriverLoaded(DriverManagerDataSource.java:100)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:132)
```

When I'm using XML configuration, data source properties are resolved OK, so this problem is not because of misconfigured PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.

Comment: it *might* be too early for property resolution it seems - from the BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor's javadoc: allowing for
 the registration of further bean definitions <i>before</i> regular
 BeanFactoryPostProcessor detection kicks in.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented wrong interface - InitializingBean seems to be the right one.
Now I'm creating bean definitions inside afterPropertiesSet() callback. Rubber duck debugging does work! Thanks everyone.